# azure function with dependency injection

Tags: azure-functions

trying to add dependency injection into .net core 3.1 azure function.
Adding Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions includes Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection version 5.0.1
This throws an error -
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

i dont know how to resolve this. i cannot downgrade DependencyInjection to version 3.xxx as it is part of the extensions package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0 in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809716/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-configuration-abstractions)

Comment: Long story short, the 5.* libraries aren't compatible with .NET Core 3.1. Downgrade.

Comment: i cannot downgrade, version 5.1 is part of Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions. when in uninstall the extensions package and try to install just dependency injection i still get a warning about detected package downgrade and it wont let me install?

Comment: You *can* downgrade, because you *have to*. Pretend the 5.* versions of the packages don't exist. Use the 3.* versions.

Comment: Okay, so now we're on .NET 6 and Azure that is supposed to be used with .NET 6 still isn't compatible?