# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have a project targeting framework of **.net6.0**. I want to upgrade to ef 7.0.0 from ef6.0.0. In my solution, I have a separate project for functionApps. There I am getting an error "`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.`".

As I have to upgraded to ef 7.0.0, all the dependencies should be at 7.0.0. As per this link, [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0 in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809716/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-configuration-abstractions), I cannot downgrade the version. Below is the function app error screenshot.

[image: FunctionApp Error]

Comment: Have you tried to add a reference manually? `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions --version 7.0.0` maybe there is already another reference to this one in another project.

Comment: Yes @Hille , I have added both the packages Entity Framework and Configuration.Abstractions of stable version 7 manually using .NET CLI Global Cmdlets - Giving the host errors on starting of the Function. But working excellently with the version 6 of both the packages.

Comment: I think that I had the same problem, my solution was a upgrade to .net 7, but it's probably only feasible if you in development stage and not production.

Comment: Yes .NET 7 is not yet released for Azure Functions except isolated version.

Comment: It is working for .NET 7 as shown practically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74473381/16630138) but when we remove the package called `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`

Comment: Runtime errors mean the correct DLLs weren't deployed along with the application. How *did* you deploy it? Did you include all the contents of the `bin/Release/.../publish` folder?

Comment: @HariKrishna, it is not possible to remove `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` in my case

Comment: @ispostback, Got it. For that, I have raised the product issue in the GitHub which needs to be fixed from backend (MSFT Azure Team). Will follow up.

Answer (score 14):

- This issue is registered in the Azure Functions Host GitHub Repository where the Function is throwing the NuGet Package load exception with Version 7 of `Entity Framework Core` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` which have been released recently.
- A few users mentioned it is working with Version 6 NuGet Packages installed in .NET 6 v4 Azure Functions and also for .NET 7 with the removal of the specific package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` as shown practically in the same SO [Forum of Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74470489/16630138), .NET 7 In-Process is not yet release for Azure Functions which will be released soon.
- You can track this GitHub Azure Functions Host Issue [8984](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8984) for the `.NET 6 v4` NuGet (EF Core & `Config.Abstractions` Versioned 7) Packages Runtime Issue and will update the answer with the fix accordingly.

Comment: This shows clear research in the solution and it helped me too..!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and I resolved it by downgrading "Microsoft.Extensions.Http" to 6.0.0.0 to match my TargetFramework net6.0

**Changes to csproj file**

[image]

Comment: That's not helpful. See *I want to upgrade to ef 7.0.0*.

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, the problem was that .net 7.0/.net 8.0 currently only supports the isolated model.
**After migrating the Azure Function to the isolated model worked!**

I also noted that if my Azure Function references some project that uses .net 7.0 packages like Entity Framework Core 7.0.0.0, even when the project targets .net 6.0 I get the same error.

See:
[Migrate Azure Function to Isolated Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net7)